# Componente Autocomplete Primefaces "desaparece da tela" após update no ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Boa tarde, estou tentando inserir um produto automaticamente após ler o código e faço a atualização dos componentes no *managedBean*. No Entanto, o componente *autocomplete* desaparece da tela depois que faço o *context.update(panelGroup)*

Obs.: A solução funciona, no entanto eu gostaria de limpar o *autocomplete* após a inserção do produto.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender o que estar acontecendo, por favor?

```
public List<Produto> produtosSugeridos(String query) {              
        lisProdutosSugeridos = produtoServico.listarTodos();        

        List<Produto> produtosFiltrado = new ArrayList<Produto>();
        for (Produto p : lisProdutosSugeridos) {
            if (Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(query), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(p.getNome()).find()
                    || Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(query), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(p.getCodigoDeBarras()).find()) {
                produtosFiltrado.add(p);
            }
        }

        if(produtosFiltrado.size() == 1 && query.length() == 13 && query.matches("[0-9]*")){            

            RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();           

            for (Produto p : produtosFiltrado) {                    
                produtoDaVenda.setProduto(p);

                adicionaProdutosNaVenda();  
                produtoDaVenda.setQuantidade(1.0);

                produtosFiltrado = new ArrayList<Produto>();

                 context.update("panelProdutos");
                 context.update("panel");
                 //Atualizo o autocomplet
                 context.update("panelInputProdu");
            }

        }       
        return produtosFiltrado;    
}
```

Aqui código na página .xhtml

```
<h:panelGroup id="panelInputProdu">
    <h:panelGrid        
<p:autoComplete
    tabindex="8"
    id="autoProduto" 
    value="#{vendaControlador.produtoDaVenda.produto}"
    completeMethod="#{vendaControlador.produtosSugeridos}" 
    var="p" itemLabel="#{p.nome}"
    converter="produtoConverter" 
    temValue="#{p}"
    minQueryLength="2" maxResults="20"                                       
    update="autoProduto,:formVenda:precoVenda">`

   <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="autoProduto,:formVenda:precoVenda" />                                     
</p:autoComplete>
     <p:watermark for="autoProduto" value="Digite o produto" />
</h:column>
```

[image: Imagem do componente]

Comment: pq vc dá um update no seu componente dentro do mb? Não seria melhor na ação do botão "Adicionar"?

Comment: Olá Adriano, se clicar no  "Adicionar" funciona,  mas nesse caso eu quero inserir automaticamente um produto ao ler o código e o usuario não vai clicar no botão. Como pode ser visto no metodo `produtosSugeridos(String query)` Por isso preciso do `context.update` no managedBean.

Answer (score 0):

na pagina eu tenho no `value` do automplete: `value="#{vendaControlador.produtoDaVenda.produto}"`

No método `produtosSugeridos(String query)` eu coloquei:

```
produtoDaVenda.setQuantidade(1.0); produtoDaVenda.setProduto(null);
```

a quantidade fica ok como pode ser visto na imagem acima, mas o autocomplete desaparece ao fazer `context.update("panelInputProdu");`

Alguém poderia me dizer o que estar acontecendo. Agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

O autocomplete está ficando dessa forma pq o retorno dele sempre é sempre um array vazio, veja que ali vc faz um `produtosFiltrado = new ArrayList<Produto>();`, dessa forma o array de retorno do método do aucomplete fica vazio.  Acredito que você esteja misturando métodos aí, pelo o que entendi tu queres selecionar um item do autocomplete e adicioná-lo em sua listagem, se sim, tente o seguinte:

```
public List <Produto> produtosSugeridos( String query ) {
  lisProdutosSugeridos = produtoServico.listarTodos();

  List<Produto> produtosFiltrado = new ArrayList<Produto>();
  for (Produto p :lisProdutosSugeridos) {
    if ( Pattern.compile( Pattern.quote( query ), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(p.getNome()).find()
        || Pattern.compile( Pattern.quote( query ), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(p.getCodigoDeBarras()).find()) {
      produtosFiltrado.add(p);
    }
  }

  return produtosFiltrado;
}

public void addProdutoAutoComplete(){
  RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
  if(produtoDavenda.getProduto != null){
    adicionaProdutosNaVenda();
    produtoDaVenda.setQuantidade(1.0);
    context.update("panelProdutos");
    context.update("panel");
    //Atualizo o autocomplet
    context.update("panelInputProdu");
  }
}
```

E no ajax do autocomplete fica da seguinte forma:

```
<p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="autoProduto,:formVenda:precoVenda" listener="#{vendaControlador.addProdutoAutoComplete}" process="@this,autoProduto"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, Adriano. Obrigado por estar tentando ajudar.

> "pelo o que entendi tu queres selecionar um item do autocomplete e adicioná-lo em sua listagem.."

Nesse caso não! Eu quero ler o codigo de um produto e automaticamente inseri-lo sem a necessidade do usuario clicar no botão "Adicionar"(Obs.: Se clicar funciona).

A situação é o seguinte: digamos que vai ter um leitor de codigo e ao encontrar o produto vai inserir. Isso tudo no managedBean, o usuario **não vai** selecionar o item na tela e **não vai clicar** no botão Adicionar.
Realmente o problema é nesse parte do código que você falou:`produtosFiltrado = new ArrayList<Produto>();` O que travei foi: Como faço ao inserir o item e dar `upadte` e o componente funcionar nomrmalmente?  darei tipo um `clear` no List ou no `Automcomplete` para que posse informar um novo códido? Isso que estou confuso!
Obs.: se deixar o `produtosFiltrado = new ArrayList<Produto>();` o componente "desaparece"  e se retirar, o componente "trava" com o produto selecionado. Como pode ser visto abaixo.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Então acredito que vc esteja usando o componente errado, visto que o autocomple por natureza retorna itens para executar uma ação, pq ao invés de usar um autocomplete, não usa um ajax em um inputtext comum? Eu faria dessa forma:    

    <h:outputText id="result" value="#{guessNumber.result}" />
        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{guessNumber.named}">
        <f:ajax listener="#{guessNumber.namedChanged}" render="result" />
    </h:inputText>